# How do I add a numpy array into cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, blob

I am creating a table where I need to store an image translated into a numerical array ( typically float values ). While I am able to create a table with the numerical array column declared as BLOB data type, I get the following invalid request error while I try to insert the data.

> *Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid list literal for image_embedding of type blob"*

I am trying to insert data like this :

```
INSERT INTO master.emp_by_embedding (site_id, emp_id, image_embedding) 
VALUES ('INDIA_01', 'AL716837', **[-1.0672206 , -1.438882  ,  1.6111488 
,  0.6600302 , -0.06482011,\n0.7914173 ,  0.78052145,  0.49402863, -0.8117229 
,  1.1979666 ,\n-0.29825854,  0.06478833,  0.998869  , -0.98645747
,  0.0959858 .... .... 0.27031496, -1.7236737 ,  1.1005085 ,  0.0200185 
, -0.9137004 ,\n-1.7611294 ,  0.08231554, -0.40587714]**) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

What is the right way to insert image data here ? I've tried to convert numerical data using listasblob (typeasblob) function but that doesn't work ( get an error - unknown function).

Answer (score 1):

Raja, can you please provide the schema of your cassandra table ? Depending on the type of `image_embedding` syntax will be different.

```
describe table master.emp_by_embedding;
```

I see a `\n` characters in the table values that will probably lead to error if a real character.

**Inserting list**

Assuming your type is a `list<double>` or `list<decimal>` here is a working QUERY.

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp_by_embedding(
 site_id text,
 emp_id text,
 image_embedding list<double>,
 PRIMARY KEY((site_id), emp_id)
);

INSERT INTO emp_by_embedding (site_id, emp_id, image_embedding)
VALUES ('INDIA_01', 'AL716837', [-1.0672206 , -1.438882 , 1.6111488 , 0.6600302 , -0.06482011, 0.7914173 , 0.78052145, 0.49402863, -0.8117229 , 1.1979666 , -0.29825854, 0.06478833, 0.998869 , -0.98645747, 0.0959858, 0.27031496, -1.7236737 , 1.1005085 , 0.0200185 , -0.9137004 , -1.7611294 , 0.08231554, -0.40587714]) 
IF NOT EXISTS;
```

**Inserting blob**

Assuming your type is a blob *(this what the error seems to tell)*, the expected value must be binary content not your list, you need to convert it first.